# How to prevent a stack overflow in IE due to unwanted recursion

Tags: javascript, ajax, internet-explorer, stack-overflow

I've been searching since a while, to no avail.

On a long form, I'm doing checks with javascript, and used the attribute "onchange" to do them. Recently, I discovered that on IE, the "onpropertychange" attribute should be used, as the "onchange" event is not handled correctly.

So now, I have for example this kind of field (not all the fields have onKeyDown or onKeyUp events):

```
<textarea name="shdescription" rows="1" cols="75" onKeyDown="textCounter(this,'shdesccounter',65)"
onKeyUp="textCounter(this,'shdesccounter',65)" onchange="checkFormValue();" onpropertychange="checkFormValue();"></textarea>
```

And now each time I make a change on a field, then it takes a few seconds before registring the change and making the check. (and more when the change is made on the textarea I described.)

Firing the IE F12 debugger, I noticed that a lot of *"SCRIPT28: Out of stack space"* and *"SCRIPT2343: Stack overflow at line:"* are fired. Following the execution of the script step by step, I noticed that the script is looping between two different ajax call to PHP scripts. I'm not sure we can talk of recursion actually, as I don't see any direct link between the two function.

So I can think only of two possibilities: either there are change triggered in the field which trigger the the ajax call again, or I am doing something wrong with my ajax calls.

Where should I look to resolve my problem? If there is need for more information, don't hesitate to ask.

PS: I don't have any problem of this sort with FF/Chrome/Opera.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll bet that one of the functions `checkFormValue()` or `textCounter()` is modifying the textbox in a way that is causing another event to fire which goes on to endlessly loop.

Try using onBlur.

Comment: If it were the case, wouldn't I have also problems in FF/Chrome/Opera and the onchange event? Because it is not the case. I only have problem with IE. Without the onpropertychange attribute, the onchange attribute doesn't trigger, and with it, I've got the problem I described.

Comment: In that case can you not use onBlur instead?

Comment: "If it were the case, wouldn't I have also problems in FF/Chrome/Opera" -- not if your callback is modifying some attribute of the textarea *other than* `value` (say `focus`).  That would cause an invocation of onpropertychange, but not onchange.

Comment: Using onBlur did the trick, thanks. Never used this event before. Can it substitute the use of onchange in my use case?

Comment: I would say it could - it's very similar and in light on the problem you've experienced it's just one of those things you learn as you go along.

Comment: Ok, good to know. To answer the question in your post, in light of what @Malvolio said, the checkFormValue() change the class to invalid if the check didn't pass for one field, and to valid in case the check passed.

Comment: @m.edmondson: could you edit your answer with the decisive information, so I can accept it?